# Unix: Last command - How do I execute a sub command for file input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, zcat

I am trying to read an on old last file, but when I use the command below
it does not work as expected. Is there a way I can do it in one line?

```
last -f `zcat /var/log/wtmp.1.gz`
```

I want to be able to read the file without decompressing the file.

The long version is the following:

```
zcat /var/log/wtmp.1.gz > /var/tmp/login
last -f /var/tmp/login
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot feed last via stdin in bash.

```
# this won't work
# zcat /var/log/wtmp.1.gz | last-
```

Side note: However with zsh shell you could

```
last -f =(zcat /var/log/wtmp-20130827.gz)
```

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88343/how-to-tell-the-last-command-to-read-from-stdin

Comment: The question isn't tagged `zsh`; why given an answer that requires it?

Comment: Answer requires nothing. It is simple `You cannot...`, as a side note I mentioned about zsh. Is that wrong.

Comment: @kAlmAcetA I see. Thank for the answer! I need to something like the following: zsh -c "last -f =(zcat /var/log/wtmp.1.gz)"